# Filtering in CUDA using Texture Memory

Tags: cuda

I'm using texture memory for image filtering in CUDA as:

```
texture<unsigned char> texMem; //deceleration
cudaBindTexture( NULL, texMem,d_inputImage,imageSize); //binding
```

However I'm not satisfied with the results at the boundary. Is there any other considerations or settings for texture memory tailored for 2D filtering?

I've seen people declear texture this way:

```
    texture<float> texMem(0,cudaFilterModeLinear);
 // what does this do?
```

Moreover, if anyone can suggest some online guide explaining how to properly set setup texture memory abstraction in CUDA, that'll be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify what kind of sampling you want using `cudaFilterMode` (could be linear or cubic).

You could look at Appendix G from the [CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) provided in path/to/cudatoolkit/doc to see this explained in detail